# PHP default value check

Tags: php, forms, input

Let say I have an input with a default value of

```
value="WEBSITE URL"
```

I only want to update my database if the default value does not equal the inputted value. Therefore, I want a way to check if the value is not the default value. Since I deal with all post variables with a single function, I cannot be specific line:

```
if($_POST['URL'] != 'WEBSITE URL') { update database }
```

I need something along the lines of:

```
foreach($_POST)
{
    if($_POST != defaultValue) { update database }
}
```

Comment: So you want to have a couple of default values in something like an array?

Comment: You should use a placeholder instead of a default value. Placeholders are not submitted with the form.

Comment: You will need to refer to the URL specifically (especially if you're wanting to grab it and insert it into a database). You could theoretically do a regex check on the values to find a `url` in $_POST, but this isn't reliable. Why can't you assign a `name` attribute to your URL value?

Comment: Thanks! placeholders is what im looking for. I never knew about that attribute! :)

Comment: It's only in newer browsers (which should be fine) but there are stuff like jquery replacements to standardize it in older browsers.

Comment: Bad coding, you should check result from cases you have. For example roles, user can be `user` or `admin`, all others will be re-defined as `user`. If user will input `superadmin` (invalid data) it will still have role `user`, if you check input with text type so check simple using `strlen > 0`.

Comment: Why is it that when I use placeholder, my jquery doesn't work with things like $(input).val();???